# Rails app not working fully through Heroku deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I managed to successfully deploy my Rails app through Heroku, but it seems to work only partially, i.e. the root_path, about_path, and login_path all work, but anything else gives me the "**We're sorry, but something went wrong.**" error. The app works in its entirety locally, however, without issue.

The app was working fine on commit [6315941](https://github.com/iforgottosave/alpha-blog/commit/631594111f08271f1d8170db6af639f087cd21d1) of the Github page for the app, and I redeployed on commit [f32ccf00](https://github.com/iforgottosave/alpha-blog/commit/f32cf001709bdeda94c9d365d57b9b36e4357c5d), which is then the app stopped working to full capacity. Advice/solutions appreciated.

```
Started GET "/users" for
 Processing by UsersController#index as HTML
   Rendered users/index.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 2.0ms | Allocations: 318)
   Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 2.1ms | Allocations: 344)
 Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 829)

 ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
```

[Heroku](https://alpha-blog-702.herokuapp.com/)

[Github](https://github.com/iforgottosave/alpha-blog)

Comment: What command `heroku logs --tail` says?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you may have not run your database migrations on Heroku? They are not run automatically by the default deploy process.

`heroku run rake db:migrate -a <your app>`

and then

`heroku ps:restart -a <your app>`

because in production mode Rails will only detect schema changes during the boot phase.